# SQL Server 2008 default select top n row

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, sql-server-2008-r2

In the MS SQL Management studio you can select [image: select top n rows]

**top n row** as an action in the table menu.
I know how configuring the number of returned rows.
I want to now if there is a way to configure to return rows in *desc ordering* ?

Comment: To all people how want to answer. I asked if it is a way (may be not) to configure it and return order by some column desc by default when I run query from the table menu as on the screenshot. I didn't ask anybody to write t-sql that can give me the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were possible to determine if there was an identity primary key you could default to using that as the descending order, this would be usefull for showing the most recent items first? But there doesn't seem to be a way to get at the template used to generate the SQL so I think the answer is NO.

Comment: Ok, I think so, also it will be a good sugar to add this feature for sql in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the generated query and add an `ORDER BY` clause to it. Management Studio can't know by which column you want to sort.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM
 (
 SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ... desc) rn
 FROM table t
 )
 WHERE rn < requiredQuantity
```